# Find lines containing all keywords in bash script

Tags: bash, grep

Essentially, I would like something that behaves similarly to:

```
cat file | grep -i keyword1 | grep -i keyword2 | grep -i keyword3
```

How can I do this with a bash script that takes a variable-length list of keyword arguments? The script should do a case-insensitive match of lines containing all keywords.

Comment: Are you asking us what the best way to do this is?

Comment: Yes. What is the most elegant/efficient way to do this in a bash script that takes a variable number of keywords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this as a script

```
#! /bin/bash
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -f <(
  P=; for k; do [ -z "$P" ] && P="/$k/" || P="$P&&/$k/"; done
  echo "$P{print}"
)
```

and invoke it as

```
script.sh keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 < file
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is efficient, and I think this is ugly, also there might be some utility for that, but:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset keywords matchlist
keywords=("$@")

for kw in "${keywords[@]}"; do
matchlist="$matchlist /$kw/ &&"
done

matchlist="${matchlist% &&}"

# awk "$matchlist { print; }" < <(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <file)
awk "$matchlist { print; }" file
```

And yes, it needs some robustness regarding special characters and stuff. It's just to show the idea.

Comment: Thanks, that's the gist of it. But how would I make the keyword match case-insensitive (like grep -i)?

Comment: You catched me! I think GNU awk has something like an IGNORECASE variable, but I'm not sure.

If it is an option, you can lowercase the inputfile when reading in and use lowercase keywords only: awk ... < <(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <file)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
keywords="keyword1|keyword2|keyword3"
while read line; do [[ $line =~ $keywords ]] && echo $line; done < file
```

**Edit**:

Here's a version that tests for all keywords being present, not just any:

```
keywords=(keyword1 keyword2 keyword3)    # or keywords=("$@")
qty=${#keywords[@]}
while read line
do
    count=0
    for keyword in "${keywords[@]}"
    do
        [[ "$line" =~ $keyword ]] && (( count++ ))
    done
    if (( count == qty ))
    then
        echo $line
    fi
 done < textlines
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used shopt before--always nice to learn something new. This gives a case-insensitive match but it matches lines containing the any of the keywords. I only want to match lines that contain all the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bash 4.0++

```
shopt -s nocasematch
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in 
        *keyword1*) f=1;;&
        *keyword2*) g=1;;&
        *keyword3*) 
            [ "$f" -eq 1 ] && [ "$g" -eq 1 ] && echo $line;;
    esac
done < "file"
shopt -u nocasematch
```

or gawk

```
gawk '/keyword/&&/keyword2/&&/keyword3/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this with grep.

```
KEYWORDS=$@
MATCH_EXPR="cat file"
for keyword in ${KEYWORDS};
do
  MATCH_EXPR="${MATCH_EXPR} | grep -i ${keyword}"
done
eval ${MATCH_EXPR}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in Perl.

For finding all lines that contain at least one of them:

```
perl -ne'print if /(keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)/i' file
```

For finding all lines that contain all of them:

```
perl -ne'print if /keyword1/i && /keyword2/i && /keyword3/i' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script called `search.sh` in bash that will search lines within a file or folder for all keywords specified:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "[-] $0 file_to_search/folder_to_search keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 ..."
    exit
fi
all_args="$@"
i=0
results=""  # this will store the cumulative results from each keyword search
for arg in $all_args; do
    if [ $i -eq 0 ]; then
        # first argument is the file/folder to search
        file_to_search="$arg"
        i=$(($i + 1))
    elif [ $i -eq 1 ]; then
        # search the file/folder with first keyword (first search)
        results=`grep --color=always -r -n -i "$arg" "$file_to_search"`
        i=$(($i + 1))
    else
        # now keep searching the results from first search for other keywords
        results=`echo "$results" | grep --color=always -i "$arg"`
        i=$(($i + 1))
    fi
done
echo "$results"
```

Example invocation of script above will search the 'tools.txt' file for 'python' and 'jira' keywords:

```
./search.sh tools.txt python jira
```